# How to give non-root user in Docker container access to a volume mounted on the host

Tags: security, docker

I am running my application in a Docker container as a non-root user. I did this since it is one of the best practices. However, while running the container I mount a host volume to it `-v /some/folder:/some/folder` . I am doing this because my application running inside the docker container needs to write files to the mounted host folder. But since I am running my application as a non-root user, it doesn't have permission to write to that folder

**Question**

Is it possible to give a nonroot user in a docker container access to the hosted volume?

If not, is my only option to run the process in docker container as root?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's no magic solution here: permissions inside docker are managed the same as permissions without docker. You need to run the appropriate `chown` and `chmod` commands to change the permissions of the directory.

One solution is to have your container run as root and use an `ENTRYPOINT` script to make the appropriate permission changes, and then your `CMD` as an unprivileged user.  For example, put the following in `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

chown -R appuser:appgroup /path/to/volume
exec runuser -u appuser "$@"
```

This assumes you have the `runuser` command available.  You can accomplish pretty much the same thing using `sudo` instead.

Use the above script by including an `ENTRYPOINT` directive in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM baseimage

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/bin/myapp"]
```

This will start the container with:

```
/bin/sh entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/myapp
```

The entrypoint script will make the required permissions changes, then run `/usr/bin/myapp` as `appuser`.

Comment: I think this would work. To make this more general, is there a way to replace `/path/to/volume` with the parameters given to `-v` command when running the container? For example if container is run with `-v /some/path:/some/path` then the `chown` command in entrypoint.sh becomes `chown -R appeaser:appuser /some/path`. Rather than hardcoding a volume name in entrypoint.sh

Comment: There's no way within the container to introspect available volume paths, but you could pass in an environment variable (`docker run -v /some/path:/some/path -e MYVOLUME=/some/path ...`), and then use `$MYVOLUME` in your `ENTRYPOINT` script.

Comment: ugh. I am getting an error `runuser` not found. How can I get that command? I am using ubuntu image..

Comment: Like I said, you can instead use `sudo`.  As in `sudo -u appuser somecommand`.  Or with a little work you could just use `su`, although I find the syntax less useful.

Comment: @larsks "have your container run as root" defies the purpose of a non-root container.

Comment: @13013SwagR I disagree. I think starting your container as `root` and then switching to a non-`root` user in your `ENTRYPOINT` script gets you *exactly* the same level of security. In either case, your service is not running as the `root` user.

Comment: This is great, but can you still pass in argument to your app in run-time?

Comment: If you design your entrypoint script appropriately, sure. Nothing here changes the way Docker works.

Comment: @larsks - I must (politely) disagree with your disagreement.

I'm no expert here but a quick Google turned up (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/root-capabilities-docker-security/ for details) which explains why starting as root and then de-escalating inside the container _does not_ give the same level of security as you'd get by specifying a non-root user via the `USER` keyword in a Dockerfile.

Comment: FYI: I turned this security discussion to another question: ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574334/docker-is-it-safe-to-switch-to-non-root-user-in-entrypoint ). So far the answers seem to suggest that while it isn't the same level of security, it is an accepted approach.

Answer (score 26):

There will throw error if host env don't have `appuser` or `appgroup`, so better to use a User ID instead of user name:

**inside your container**, run

```
appuser$ id
```

This will show:

> uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)

From host env, run:

```
mkdir -p /some/folder
chown -R 1000:1000 /some/folder
docker run -v /some/folder:/some/folder [your_container]
```

**inside your container**, check

```
ls -lh
```

to see the user and group name, if it's not `root`, then it's should worked.

Comment: Is there something we can do if `appuser` is not installed?

Comment: @bananabrann `appuser` is not a tool, but some username, like `admin` etc., decided by your container's `USER admin` instruction.

Comment: Oh I’m dumb —I didn’t make the distinction it was app” “user” and not the new word “appuser”

Comment: @bananabrann it's alright, I've made the same mistake

Comment: Is this really possible even if on the host there is no user / group with this ID? Sounds strange

Comment: This doesn't work for me using "Docker version 20.10.21, build 20.10.21-0ubuntu1~20.04.2".

I can see that the mount point folder gest created and gets the correct user and permissions, if I start the image without "-v". But as soon as I run the image and mount a volume on the folder, it gets the uid:gid combination of the folder on the host machine.

Answer (score 16):

In the specific situation of using an image built from a custom Dockerfile, you can do the following (using example commands for a debian image):

```
    FROM baseimage
    ...
    RUN useradd --create-home appuser
    USER appuser
    RUN mkdir /home/appuser/my_volume
    ...
```

Then mount the volume using

```
-v /some/folder:/home/appuser/my_volume
```

Now `appuser` has write permissions to the volume as it's in their home directory. If the volume has to be mounted outside of their home directory, you can create it and assign `appuser` write permissions as an extra step within the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you that is a very good answer. The best.

Answer (score 1):

I found it easiest to recursively apply Linux ACL (Access Control Lists) permissions on the host directory so the non root host user can access volume contents.

```
sudo setfacl -m u:$(id -u):rwx -R /some/folder
```

To check who has access to the folder:

```
getfacl /some/folder
```

Writing to the volume will create files and directories with host user id which might not be desirable for host -> container transfer. Writing can be disabled with just giving :rx permission instead of :rwx.

To enable writing, add a mirror ACL policy in a container allowing container user id full access to volume parent path.