# How to set copy all environment variables from root user to another specific user

Tags: security, docker, environment-variables

In my docker container I am running a command as a specific user like this from `entrypoint.sh`:

`sudo -u appuser "$@"`

This works fine, however, it doesn't set any of the environment variables that get created by using the `--link` option while running the container.

**Question**

Is it possible to set all environment variables that exist for a root user to some other specific user (in this example `appuser`)

Note: related question to this discussion. This is the reason I can't just use the `USER` command [How to give non-root user in Docker container access to a volume mounted on the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397548/how-to-give-non-root-user-in-docker-container-access-to-a-volume-mounted-on-the)

Comment: Thanks for making this a new question rather than turning that other answer into a giant comment thread!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sudo` command, because it is designed as a tool for privilege escalation, intentionally sanitizes the environment before switching to a new user id.  If you take a look at the `sudo` man page, you'll find:

> ```
>  -E, --preserve-env
>              Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing
>              environment variables.  The security policy may return an error if the user does not
>              have permission to preserve the environment.
> ```

So instead of `sudo -u appuser somecommand`, just use `sudo -E -u appuser somecommand`.

The `runuser` command is provided by the `util-linux` package in recent versions of Ubuntu, and does not perform any environment initialization by default.  For example:

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu /bin/bash
root@ded49ffde72e:/# runuser --help

Usage:
 runuser [options] -u <user> <command>
 runuser [options] [-] [<user> [<argument>...]]
[...]
```

This is with Ubuntu Xenial (but the `runuser` command also appears to be available on `ubuntu:vivid`, but *is not* available under `ubuntu:trusty`).

So your options are:

- Use `sudo -E`, or
- Use a more recent Ubuntu image

Comment: I came back to answer my own question but you are too quick for me. `-E` to the rescue!

Comment: For some reason, sudo -E does not preserve PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH for me...
Other environment variables are preserved... I don't get it...
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
   
sudo -E -u bryanloz bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

Comment: `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will not be preserved because `sudo` is setuid root, and the operating system itself will not permit you to pass `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` across a setuid boundary (see the [`ld.so` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). `$PATH` is probably being reset by the `secure_path` setting in your `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Thanks, man! You saved my day! I was troubleshooting that shit for a few hours now...!