# Using Docker on WIndows10 Access right problem. Want to mount

Tags: docker

I want to mount folder in Docker container.
Using Command Prompt with WSL2.
Then, I typed command like...

```
docker run -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v \C\Users\<username>\Desktop\mounted_folder:/created_in_run <image_id> bash
```

conditions:
`id -u:1000`
`id -g:1000`

In container, I found that `created_in_run` folder is for user `root`.(not `1000`)

like...(type with `ls -la`)

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 7 05:11 created_in_run
```

Then I tried to `touch test` with `created_in_run` folder.

But, respond is like...

```
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied
```

I couldn't find out how to fix this.

Would you please tell me how to solve this matter???

Comment: You're presumably not running as `root`. Either run as `root`, or use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Docker` (or `containerd`) daemon running with `root` privileges and creating new folder under `root` user. So `created_in_run` owned by `root`
2. `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)` means that inside container's user logged in bash is an user with UID → `1000`. This parameter do not affect to mounted folder permissions.
3. Because of your container internal user is non root (because of step ②) and folder mounted with `root` permissions → `UID 1000`'s user don't have access to it.

#### How to solve this problem:

Just create `created_in_run` folder manually before running container and set correct ownership to it:

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 created_in_run
```

Or change ownership after folder will be created by running command above (You must to change ownership at external folder because docker internal user don't have `sudo` privileges)

Also you can check related question and solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397548/how-to-give-non-root-user-in-docker-container-access-to-a-volume-mounted-on-the).